# Vertical Slider (Bootstrap Carousel)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im making a slider (carousel) and i already done it but i want my slider to slide up/down in short vertical sliding can anyone help me about it this is my mark up

```html
 <div class="bs-example">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Carousel indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            </ol>
            <!-- Wrapper for carousel items -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="img/image1.jpg" alt="First Slide"/>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/image2.jpg" alt="Second Slide"/>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/image3.jpg" alt="Third Slide"/>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/image4.jpg" alt="Forth Slide"/>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/image5.jpg" alt="Fifth Slide" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Carousel controls -->
            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </a>
            <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Im just using a simple bootstrap carousel.

PS. Im new in using SLIDER or Carousel

And also i want my image to be fitted on the screen the size of my image is (1920 x 1080) how can i do that.

Thank You for advance I hope you can help me :)

Comment: I already saw that post but i dont know why its not working in my slider

Comment: Hi i already done with the up and down slide but i want the arrows on the top and bottom